# No axis named error in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

My program grabs files meeting certain specs in a directory, reads in the labels, narrows down the columns to the specified ones, and then should create a csv summarizing the files. I want it to read in the labels for the axes, print them on the first line of the file, and then print the means of the axes in question on each subsequent line.

The error I'm getting is that there's no such axes, and when I googled the error it seems that people are getting that error when they add a column to a dataframe. I'm just asking for the existing ones.

```
file_list = [f for f in os.listdir(pathname) if f.lower().endswith('.xls') and not 'map' in f.lower() and not 'check' in f.lower()]
temp_df = reduce_df(read_in(file_list[0]))
labels = temp_df.columns
print labels # I printed this to the screen for troubleshooting purposes
with open(summary_file, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(labels)

    for f in file_list:
        temp_df = reduce_df(read_in(f))
        print temp_df.columns#ditto. this should match the previous one        
        new_row = [temp_df.mean(col) for col in temp_df.columns]
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

-output-

```
Using Python parser to sniff delimiter
Index([u'Product Mass Flow (kg/hr)', u'TC 03 (C)', u'MKS NO ppm (-)', u'MKS NO2 ppm (-)', u'MKS NH3 ppm (-)', u'MKS N2O ppm (-)', u'MKS H2O (%)', u'NOx Calc MKS (-)', u'MKS2 NO ppm (-)', u'MKS2 NO2 ppm (-)', u'MKS2 NH3 ppm (-)', u'MKS2 N2O ppm (-)', u'MKS2 H2O (%)', u'NOx Calc MKS2 (-)'], dtype='object')
Using Python parser to sniff delimiter
Index([u'Product Mass Flow (kg/hr)', u'TC 03 (C)', u'MKS NO ppm (-)', u'MKS NO2 ppm (-)', u'MKS NH3 ppm (-)', u'MKS N2O ppm (-)', u'MKS H2O (%)', u'NOx Calc MKS (-)', u'MKS2 NO ppm (-)', u'MKS2 NO2 ppm (-)', u'MKS2 NH3 ppm (-)', u'MKS2 N2O ppm (-)', u'MKS2 H2O (%)', u'NOx Calc MKS2 (-)'], dtype='object')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(program trace here)", line 50, in <module>
    new_row = [temp_df.mean(col) for col in temp_df.columns]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3490, in stat_func
    skipna=skipna, numeric_only=numeric_only)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3961, in _reduce
    axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 295, in _get_axis_number
    .format(axis, type(self)))
ValueError: No axis named Product Mass Flow (kg/hr) for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

As requested, my defs - the data logger has a bunch of stuff in it that has confusing names or is simply not necessary. I'm reducing to just the stuff I want to summarize:

```
def read_in(filename):
    current_df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = None, skiprows = range(11))     
    return current_df

def reduce_df(temp_df):
    columns = temp_df.columns
    columns = [column for column in columns if 'mks' in column.lower() or 'mass flow' in column.lower() or 'tc 03' in column.lower()]
    return temp_df[columns]
```

Comment: I think we need the source for `reduce_df`. Also, if there a particular reason why you would not use `df.to_csv` instead of rolling your own loop?

Comment: Oh, because I am brand new to Pandas and I've used this method before, so I haven't yet explored that aspect.

Comment: That is probably a way to go.

Comment: looking at the doccumentation for to_csv, I don't see how it would work for this application. I need a single csv with 1 row with the means for the values for each of dozens of files - dozens of files summarized in one document.

Comment: Say you load all of those files, compute means (checkout `df.describe`), make a new dataframe with only means and save that.

Comment: I could, but it wouldn't solve the problem at hand, which is that I can't figure out how to identify them. They're identical and yet I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out (I will look into describe and to_csv) but here's what's currently working:

```
with open(summary_file, 'wb') as outfile:
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(labels)

for f in file_list:
    temp_df = reduce_df(read_in(f))
    new_row = [value for value in temp_df.mean()] #if you don't do the value for value part, you end up with the column and value for each all in one cell
    new_row.insert(0, f) #I added this to include the filename in the summary file for the row the stuff in that row applied to       
    writer.writerow(new_row)
```